# Loading localized xib file from resource bundle (not main)

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, cocoapods

I have created a resource bundle using CocoPad which contains localized strings, images and xib files.  I have no problem loading localized strings and images but I am having problem loading xib files using a similar approach.  Here is One of the methods I tried:

```
NSString *nibName = @"MyTestViewController";
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   URLForResource:@"MyTestResources"                                                        withExtension:@"bundle"]];


NSString* path= [resourceBundle pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle* nibBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

return [[MyTestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
```

I got 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (not yet loaded)' with name

I have printed out the files in the nibBundle and the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw in the [Apple Developer web](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW24) site that

In UIKit, applications can load nib files only from their main bundle and so fewer options are needed.  But I want to know if there is any other alternatives.